# Reset formulas in cells using macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to put a formula in a cell using a macro. Here is my current code. I get error code 1004.

```
Sub Reset_formula()
Worksheets("Dagbok").Range("K6").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Data!$C$3:$J$4;MATCH(Data!$O$4;Data!$B$3:$B$4;0);MATCH(Dagbok!K5;Data!$C$2:$J$2;0))=0;"""";INDEX(Data!$C$3:$J$4;MATCH(Data!$O$4;Data!$B$3:$B$4;0);MATCH(Dagbok!K5;Data!$C$2:$J$2;0)));"""")"
End Sub
```

I have tried reading about it in these pages but i can't get it to work.
[Source 1](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42784)
[Source 2](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42204&highlight=formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange the `;` as separators for `,` and it should work just fine.

Explanation: in VBA you need to enter all formulas using the US-notation for formulas.

```
Worksheets("Dagbok").Range("K6").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Data!$C$3:$J$4,MATCH(Data!$O$4,Data!$B$3:$B$4,0),MATCH(Dagbok!K5,Data!$C$2:$J$2,0))=0,"""",INDEX(Data!$C$3:$J$4,MATCH(Data!$O$4,Data!$B$3:$B$4,0),MATCH(Dagbok!K5,Data!$C$2:$J$2,0))),"""")"
```

Comment: Thanky you!
Worked like a charm.
Changed my listseparators now as well from the control panel :)